# software updater doesn't work

Tags: updates

I have 20.04.1 LTS. Software updater is set to install updates daily, security -- automatically, and any other to be displayed immediately.
Today, the software updater reported on some new updates. I confirmed the installation. However, the updater got frozen. That happened twice. Please advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt update and Ubuntu Software get stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270122/apt-update-and-ubuntu-software-get-stuck)

Answer (score -1):

The proposed answer was checked out and found irrelevant. Thanks anyway. What I suggest is to control the settings made in the program "Software & Updates" as it apparently was in my case.

Comment: What were the settings you changed?

Comment: Ubuntu Software: all checked (not Source code). Other Software: all unchecked. Updates: Automatically -- daily. Security -- download & install automatically. Other updates -- display immediately. Notify of a new version -- for any new version. The latter was responded by offering me Ubuntu 20.10. That I accepted right away. The above settings remained. And what I found useful was setting Updater a Startup program.